# query using wpdb in wordpress gets me no result

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I get no result unless i cut the string title to "Gocomma 10W QI Wireless Fast Charger Car Mount Holder " ...

```
 $title1="Gocomma 10W QI Wireless Fast Charger Car Mount Holder - 2pcs (it)";  

 $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%%%s%%' and post_status='publish'",$title1);

 $post_if = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

any help appreciated!